# how to implement the hasNext method in sinlgly linkedlist iterator in java?

Tags: java

Here is the code implementing the hasNext method in a singly linkedlist iterator, but I don't understand why implement this method in this way.

```
private class LinkedListIterator implements ListIterator
{
  . . .
   public boolean hasNext()
   {
      if (position == null)
         return first != null;
      else
         return position.next != null;
   }
   . . .
}
```

Can I just do this in the following way?

```
private class LinkedListIterator implements ListIterator
{
  . . .
   public boolean hasNext()
   {
      if (position.next == null)
         return false;
      else
         return true;
   }
   . . .
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it both ways. It depends on what the rest of the class looks like. If you have a "dummy" node representing the position before the first element, you can do it the second way. If that position is represented by `position == null`, you'll have to do it the first way. Personally, I prefer the dummy node approach so that you don't have to worry about `null` checks.